# Machine Learning algorithm for a time series like stock market prediction in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark

I am currently studying about Apache spark library Mllib, which contain machine learning library in which I would like to create a machine learning model for future prediction.
but all the result was disappointing, usually the r2 will either be around 0 or negative for all the regression algorithm.
**is there any machine learning that will output a better r2 value than just 0 or negative?**
and **why all the machine learning fail to do price forecasting?**
the machine learning I used include 
-Linear Regression
-Generalized Regression
-DecisionTreeRegression
-GBTRegression
-IsotonicRegression
-RandomForestRegression
My data look like this
[image]

```
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('predictionEthereum').getOrCreate()
dataset = spark.read.csv('C:\\Users\\supaw\\Documents\\ethereumHistoricalData.csv',header = True,inferSchema=True)
dataset.show(1)

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
vectorAssembler =VectorAssembler(inputCols=['Unix'],outputCol='features')
stock_vol_df = vectorAssembler.transform(dataset)
stock_vol_df = stock_vol_df.select('features','Price')
stock_vol_df.show(10)
split = stock_vol_df.randomSplit([0.7,0.3])
train_df = split[0]
test_df = split[1]

from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression

aft = LinearRegression(featuresCol='features', labelCol = 'Price',maxIter=10,regParam=0.3,elasticNetParam=0.8)
aft_model = aft.fit(train_df)
aft_predictions = aft_model.transform(test_df)
aft_predictions.show(10)
aft_predictions_price = aft_model.transform(future_prediction_df)

aft_evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(
    labelCol="Price", predictionCol="prediction", metricName="r2")
r2 = aft_evaluator.evaluate(aft_predictions_price)
r2test = aft_evaluator.evaluate(aft_predictions)
print("R2 on real data = %g" % r2)
print("R2 on test data = %g" %r2test)
aft_predictions_price.show(10)
```